# List of items from the inverside side of a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I have a document that has revisions in my database. The document table contains metadata that is universal for the document and the revision has the content. Currently I can get the document with the correct revision.

What I would like to do is get a list of Documents by all of the revisions with the mappings.

Here are my two entitys:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
   @Id
   @Column(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_REVISION_ID")
   private DocumentRevisionEntity revision;
}

@Entity
public class DocumentRevisionEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name="DOCUMENT_REVISION_ID")
   private int id;

   @Column(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
   private int documentId
}
```

So what kind of JPA query I would like to query all of the revisions but have the return type be of `Document`.

Comment: What do you mean with: "`List<Document>` by all of the revisions" ?? Do you mean to get a list of documents including for each document its different revisions ??

Comment: @CarlitosWay yes, sorry I'll fix that, but the idea is I want to get all the revisions but get them as `Document`.

Comment: I can't understand well... could be this what you want: `SELECT Document doc WHERE doc.revision IN (listOfRevisions)`? If yes, I can detail

Comment: A pseudo query kind of would look like: `SELECT Document FROM revision`.  Normally you would have a `List<Revision>` with a document as the child but I was wondering if you could go from this way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do what you want is to modify your `Document` Entity.

You will need to add a `List<DocumentRevisionEntity>` that it will represent all revisions associated to a `Document` instance... Example:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
@Id
@Column(name="DOCUMENT_ID")
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_REVISION_ID")
private DocumentRevisionEntity revision;  // This is the last revision!

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="DOCUMENT_ID") // unidirectional one-to-many, works for JPA2.0!!
private List<DocumentRevisionEntity> revisions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

then when you retrieve a document from your persistence layer, you can retrieve also its associated revisions!

**BEWARE!** By default, @OneToMany relations are LAZY, and it will be loaded only when required! (this is, when you call the method `getRevisions()` from a `Document`entity managed by an `EntityManager`). Depending of your context, this configuration can cause the `N+1` subselect problem, so beware.

**If you don't want to modify your entity**... you can test this query:

`SELECT doc, rev FROM Document doc, DocumentRevisionEntity rev WHERE doc.id = rev.documentId`

However, when you call: `query.getResultList()` from this query; it will bring a `List<Object[]>` where each element consists of an array as: array[0] = Document, array[1] = DocumentRevisionEntity ... If there are documents with many versions, these documents will be repeated at the result list...

Comment: The exercise was to try not to add another property, but if I have to I will, just a thought experiment, let me test out that query and see what happens and I will report back.